# android 4.0 change titlebar layout to the old 2.x style?

Tags: android, android-layout

I have had to compile my app for the 4.0 sdk to run on 4.0 devices.

I am wanting to change the title bar layout to be the same as the previous layout used in the 2.x sdks...

I am thinking there may be a way to get the 2.x layout file and then replace the title bar layout in the 4.0 with this layout file.

How can I do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Did u try to set the theme to

```
android:theme="@android:style/Theme.Light"
```

Or .Black in your application tag in the manifest instead of choosing the default Holo theme?